# no inferences with DL queries in OWL - API

Tags: semantic-web, ontology, owl, protege, dlquery

I am trying to write a query

> Hospitals and hasNameWithWords value "center"^^string

This query returns me the instances that has the hospitals that has "center" in its name in Protege 4.2 with FACT++ reasoner as well as Hermit reasoner

but when i input the same query in the OWL-API's DL Query Example thats available in the website 
http://sourceforge.net/p/owlapi/code/ci/aef6981535f07a2d0d44c394b9f4d5415f36025a/tree/contract/src/test/java/org/coode/owlapi/examples/DLQueryExample.java

I don't get any result.

But it gives me result when i write simple queries such as

> Hospitals

Is it because the reasoner in the code is not able to make the inference?

What other reasoner would be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class you use as example (`DLQueryExample.java`) relies on an OWL-API built-in *structural reasoner* (`OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new StructuralReasonerFactory();`).

This type of reasoner is fairly simple and is not suited for complex queries as yours. It can however provide answers on the class hierarchy: This is why you get some results with the straightforward query `Hospitals`.

What you need to do is to set your code to either use Hermit or FACT++. I give the example with [Hermit](http://hermit-reasoner.com/):

- [Download](http://hermit-reasoner.com/) HermiT jar file and add it to the class path of your project.
- In your class, replace the line `OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new StructuralReasonerFactory();` by: `OWLReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new Reasoner.ReasonerFactory();`. You should have to import `org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner` in order to make it work.
- We just replaced the default reasoner by HermiT. The rest of the code should stay the same and your query should now work.
- You could try [FaCT++](http://code.google.com/p/factplusplus/) and [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet) and compare speed, etc...